# Why isn't my foldmethod being set in my ftplugin file?

Tags: vim

I have a file called `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/stylus.vim` with this contents:

```
setlocal foldmethod=indent
setlocal foldnestmax=1
setlocal foldlevelstart=1
echo 'Stylus file loaded!'
```

Everything except `foldmethod` is set correctly, and "Stylus file loaded!" is echoed when I open a stylus file (just to confirm that it actually gets loaded.)

But `foldmethod` is set to `marker`. Why isn't it getting set correctly? Is it possible that the syntax file (or similar) is overriding my setting?

---

Edit: I have grepped through all files in `vim-stylus` for "foldmethod" and "fdm" and found nothing, so it's definitely not overriding my foldmethod.

Edit again: I just found out that you can trace where a setting was last changed using `:verbose set foldmethod?`, and I found out that the fold method is set in `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim` which looks like this:

```
setlocal foldmethod=marker
setlocal foldmarker=Section:,End\ of\ section
```

Now why on earth is my html ftplugin file getting executed for my stylus file..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that the `ftplugin` vim scripts for many languages can be executed for a single file. For example, a `haml` file can have embedded coffeescript, css etc. and I'm guessing that since the `haml` syntax for vim includes embedding those languages, Vim runs the `ftplugin` scripts for them.

For that reason, I've gotten into the habit of wrapping my `ftplugin` files in a block like this:

```
if &filetype == 'haml'
  " ...
end
```

This makes sure that my settings are only applied for the file types they are intended for.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine which script last set an option with the `:verbose` command. In this case:

```
:verbose set foldmethod?
```

(with the question mark as part of the command)

It is likely you want to put your ftplugin in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` instead of `~/.vim/ftplugin/` so it loads after, and overrides the system ftplugin.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply, it was essential in figuring out what was happening, but since it doesn't actually answer the question I've added the solution myself below.